# DatabaseGeneratedOption doesn't work in Dapper.FastCRUD

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, dapper, dapper-fastcrud

I setup my mapping like this:

```
[Table("Opportunity")]
public partial class Opportunity
{
    // Other columns
    ...

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long OPPORTUNITY_ID { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public long? OPPORTUNITY_VALUE { get; set; }

    // Other columns
    ...
}
```

My unit test is setup like this:

```
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity
            {
                DATE_CREATED_UTC = DateTime.UtcNow,
                OWNER_USER_ID = TestConstants.USER_ID,
                OPPORTUNITY_NAME = "unitTest-Opportunity",
                PROBABILITY = 50,
                BID_CURRENCY = "USD",
                BID_AMOUNT = 6000,
                BID_TYPE = "Fixed Bid",
                OPPORTUNITY_STATE = "OPEN",
                OPPORTUNITY_DETAILS = "UNIT TEST OPPORUNITY DETAIL",
                VISIBLE_TO = "EVERYONE"
            };
        OppService.Add(opp);
        Opportunity fromDB = OppService.Get(opp.OPPORTUNITY_ID);
        OppService.Update(fromDB);
```

The last line would crash with the error:  **The column "OPPORTUNITY_VALUE" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.**

What am I doing wrong?  I am not modifying that column value at all.  Here is the full error stack:

```
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader) in D:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 3397
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command) in D:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 1346
   at Dapper.FastCrud.SqlStatements.GenericSqlStatements`1.UpdateById(IDbConnection connection, TEntity keyEntity, ISqlStatementOptionsGetter statementOptions)
   at Dapper.FastCrud.DapperExtensions.Update[TEntity](IDbConnection connection, TEntity entityToUpdate, Action`1 statementOptions)
   at MyProject.Data.Repository`1.Update(T entity) in C:\MyFolder\Core\MyProject.Data\Repository.cs:line 80
   at MyProject.Service.Base.ModelService`1.Update(T entity) in C:\MyFolder\Core\MyProject.Service\Base\ModelService.cs:line 38
   at MyProject.Service.Base.InstanceEntityService`2.Update(T entity) in C:\MyFolder\Core\MyProject.Service\Base\InstanceEntityService.cs:line 72
   at MyProject.Service.OpportunityService.Update(Opportunity entity) in C:\MyFolder\Core\MyProject.Service\OpportunityService.cs:line 21
   at MyProject.Test.Service.OpportunityServiceTests.OpportunitiesCRUDTest() in C:\MyFolder\Test\Core\Service\OpportunityServiceTest.cs:line 22
Result Message: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The column "OPPORTUNITY_VALUE" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.
```

CREATE statement for the table Opportunity:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Opportunity](
    [OPPORTUNITY_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    // Other columns
    [BID_CURRENCY] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [BID_AMOUNT] [bigint] NULL,
    [BID_TYPE] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [BID_DURATION] [int] NULL,
    [OPPORTUNITY_VALUE]  AS (case when [BID_TYPE]='Fixed Bid' AND [BID_AMOUNT] IS NOT NULL then [BID_AMOUNT] when [BID_TYPE]='Fixed Bid' AND [BID_AMOUNT] IS NULL then NULL when [BID_AMOUNT] IS NOT NULL AND [BID_DURATION] IS NOT NULL then [BID_AMOUNT]*[BID_DURATION] when [BID_DURATION] IS NULL then [BID_AMOUNT]  end) PERSISTED,
    [SEQUENCE_ID] [int] NULL,
    [DELETED] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DELETED_DATE_UTC] [datetime] NULL,
    [DELETED_USER_ID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OPPORTUNITY] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [INSTANCE_ID] ASC,
    [OPPORTUNITY_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Could you provide the design of your table Opportunity as well (CREATE TABLE statement)?

Comment: Hi MoonStorm, thanks for the quick reply.  I added the CREATE statement for the relevant section.  Not sure what other design you need, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks. One last question: what T4 template did you use to generate the entity classes?

Comment: Hi MoonStorm, sorry for the late reply, but I think it was hand coded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the current version of `Dapper.FastCrud` doesn't properly support computed columns. Please watch for a resolution to [this ticket](https://github.com/MoonStorm/Dapper.FastCRUD/issues/22).

**UPDATE:** The problem was fixed in 2.3.0.